# Я не понимаю как сделать

Tags: c++

Улитка ползет по вертикальному шесту высотой H метров, поднимаясь за день на A метров, а за ночь спускаясь на B метров. На какой день улитка доползет до вершины шеста?

Формат входных данных

Программа получает на вход целые неотрицательные числа H, A, B, причем H > B. Числа не превосходят 100.
Формат выходных данных

Программа должна вывести одно натуральное число. Гарантируется, что A > B.

Sample Input:
10
3
2
Sample Output:
8

Comment: `(H - A)/(A-B) + 1`?)

Comment: Ой, какие воспоминания :) задачка из класса третьего...

Answer (score 1):

Ну подумайте сами - в последний день ей не придется опускаться, правда? :)
Значит, в предыдущий день она должна доползти до высоты `H-A`, в сутки проползая по `A-B` метров.

Например, для ваших данных `A-B = 1`, заползти надо на высоту `H-A=7` метров - итого, 7 дней. Плюс последний, когда она доползет до вершины - восьмой...

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int  h,a,b;
cin >> h >> a >>b;
int day;
day = (h-a)/(a-b)+1;
cout << day;
}
```